# AngularJS ng-options not binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I'm struggling to get a select in the view to update when the model changes.  I'm using `ng-options` as follows.

```
<select ng-options="item as item.empName for item in employees track by item.ID" ng-model="emp.selected">
```

To show the issue here's the simplest case I can construct.

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.employees = [
   {
    "empName": "John",
    "ID": 1
   },
];

setTimeout(function(){ 
    $scope.employees = [
       {
        "empName": "John",
        "ID": 1
       },
       {
        "empName": "Sam",
        "ID": 1
       },
       {
        "empName": "Frank",
        "ID": 1
       }];
    }, 100);


}]);
```

The select is showing 'John' and never updates to show the additional names.  Adding `$scope.$apply();` doesn't help.

Comment: You should not use `setTimeout` with angular, it is not compatible with the angular `$digest` loop.  if you *must* use a timeout, use `$timeout` instead.  however, given that you created this sample to show the issue, I suspect the problem is something else.

Comment: it is worth noting that `$scope.$apply()` does indeed work here, assuming you add it at the correct point in your code.  http://plnkr.co/edit/HB3cA6StEicr391jLnXq.  This is not a recommended solution to the problem, however.....

Comment: You can use setTimeout but its not the recommended way in angular. I ran your code and it worked for me. Do you see any errors in the log?

Comment: Hi Calies.  Yes this is a sample. $timeout still doesn't work so the problem must be somewhere else though.  I have no idea where.

Comment: Hi Naveen, no errors in the log.

Comment: this sample doesn't serve to illustrate your problem sufficiently, unfortunately.  You should try to present a more representative example of your actual code that isn't working, since using `$timeout` or `$scope.$apply()` does indeed make the sample functional;  also, using a timeout in general isn't a good option for angular, so perhaps with more code we can assist you in finding a better logic pattern.

Comment: Hi I have figured out what was wrong.  I'm using http://materializecss.com/ and there is apparently some issue they have with 'select'.  I ran the same code while not using materialize and it worked.  Sorry to waste your time - I should've thought of that.

Comment: You should update ID's for other employees, as you are tracking with ID's. so that model gets updated correctly. See below answer section

Answer (score 0):

you need to use $timeout, not setTimeout

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't help!  It still doesn't update.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be ngModal if i am not wrong. Just change ngModel value and check

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I re-wrote the code. You can do a watch on that model and update accordingly. Remember to update ID's because you are tracking them with ID.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('InputCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout',function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.employees = [{
            "empName": "John",
            "ID": 1
        }, ];
 // watch on employees model, so that you get updated value.
        $scope.$watch("employees", function(newv, old, scope) {
            $scope.employees = newv;
            console.log(newv)
        }, true);

        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.employees = [{
                "empName": "John",
                "ID": 1
            }, {
                "empName": "Sam",
                "ID": 2
            }, {
                "empName": "Frank",
                "ID": 3
            }];
        }, 100);


    }]);
```

In your html to cross verify add  `Name :{{emp.selected.empName}}`